# How to do "Allow customer register as Seller" magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, registration

I'm new in Magento and I'm doing a project, it has one of the requirements that "Allow customer register as Seller". But I have no idea how to do it, please help. Thanks.

Comment: You can not create customer as a seller in Magento default. You need to find a marketplace extension which will `allow customer as a seller`

Comment: @thanhdv2811 I'm learning programming on magento. This is an exercise and I have to find a way to do it :(

Comment: @ThanhTN It means you want to register customer as seller or seller group?

Comment: @Raj i want to register customer as seller

Comment: @ThanhTN Have you checked in magento admin>Customers>Customer Groups Section? Where you can create your customer groups.

Comment: You must use a third parth extension how offer you a marketplace

Comment: This requires creating an attribute for the customer, in addition to the frontend, the customer will check the checkbox for register as the seller or not

Comment: @ThanhTN Then you can easily do it by creating observer event for customer registration after then change customer group into seller. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear enough. If you want to create a marketplace module from scratch. You may have 2 options of differentiate a normal and seller customer

1) Create a custom customer attribute say register as seller with option Yes or no. You can fill that value giving customer as choice or by programmatically.

2) Create a new customer group as seller by this you can again differentiate by customer group Id in your application.

Comment: I think it is the first option, how to do that?

Comment: Its a long task in try to finish it in short. As mentioned you need to create a custom module. In installer script you can write code to create a new customer attribute. Then you can modify the default registration page and place that attribute which will give customer an option to choose if they want be seller. Or you can create a new registration page for sellers and fill that attribute programatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can try free extension for your requirement.

https://cedcommerce.com/magento-extensions/marketplace-basic

Hope so it's help you.